# Why R function vapply returns sometimes an atomic vector and sometimes a matrix?

Tags: r, matrix, vector

I inherited the code of a co-worker and now I'm trying to solve some issues that arose in the last days (Unfortunately I don't have time to doctor ALL the code and I'm approaching each bug as pragmatically as possible). In particular, a bug obligates the program to work with at least to paramaters (when one should be enough).

```
var_pre <- vapply(1:repetitions, function (i) {...}, numeric(parameters))
```

This vapply seems to be the source of the bug. The function in the vapply produces n atomic vectors of length = parameters (where n = *repetitions*). The vapply will produce an **atomic vector** of length = *repetitions* if parameters = 1.

For instance, If parameters = 1 and repetitions = 3, function will produce [1] 1, [1] 2, [1] 3. And var_pre will store

```
[1] 1 2 3.
```

However, if parameters > 1, the output will be a **matrix** with as many rows as *parameters* and number of columns equal to *repetitions*.

For instance, If parameters = 2 and repetitions = 3, function will produce [1] 1 2, [1] 3 4, [1] 5 6. And var_pre will store a matrix

```
    [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]  1    3    5
[2,]  2    4    6
```

Since var_pre is further processed in the code, this issues destroys the overall workflow of the program. I want to solve this problem in the cleanest way possible, without messing with the function. I have to understand why vapply is producing results of different class.

Is there an explanation for this?

EDIT: The program uses the matrix form later. Therefore, when parameters = 1 and repetitions = 3, I need a matrix like

```
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]   1    2    3
```

Comment: Couldn't you just add a line like `if (!is.matrix(var_pre)) var_pre <- matrix(var_pre, nrow = 1)` after this step? Anyways, my guess as to *why* this happens is the intention was probably simplify the result as much as possible, i.e. a vector result can only be returned in the case of where `FUN.VALUE = numeric(1)`.